# Change app icon of exe in JetBrains Rider

Tags: exe, jetbrains-ide, rider

I searched the IDE and online but didn't find anything so I'm asking:

Is there any way to change the application icon of the executable file for the current project in JetBrains Rider?

Comment: Related issue: [RIDER-18888](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-18888)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For now, Rider doesn't have UI for that, but you can do it from code. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> on a project or Select "Edit 'YourProjectFile'" from the right-click menu to edit the project file and add these lines into the Project element:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>YourIcon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
</PropertyGroup>
```

`YourIcon.ico` is the project directory based path where your icon is located.